# Hash Function for integers below 5000?

Tags: c, hashmap, hashtable, hash

Which is the best and the simplest hash function which generate unique hash values for integers below 5000?

Actual problem is that I have an integer array of size around 50 containing values between 1 to 5000. Now I have to do reverse mapping i.e given a value and I have to find out the index at which it is stored. I know that it can be done by using binary search as my array is sorted.

Please don't suggest any hash libraries for C.

Comment: Why can't you use the number as its own hash?

Comment: @Blender: yes that possible but in that case I have to create a Hash Table of size 5000 and that's why I came here to find a better way. If I don't get any, I will go for that only.

Comment: If the numbers range from `1...5000`, then there are `5000` possible hashes (assuming you want unique hashes, which makes sense for searching). Either way you will be creating `5000` hashes, so why not go for the trivial solution?

Comment: @blender: actually I have a constant array of fixed size 50 and the value of this not going to change in the entire life cycle of the project. So I already have the set of values and I want to generate unique hash for those values only. If it is a generic case then the thing you are saying is absolutely correct. If you want the values, I can also provide that.

Answer (score 5):

Unless 5 KB of array space for 8-bit (`char`) values is too big, don't bother with a hash - use the numbers as indexes into an array of characters, storing 1 to indicate that the number is used and 0 to indicate it is not used.  You can reduce that further by using the array as a bit map (so you need about 625 bytes to store 5000 bits) for the storage, plus a little code to calculate the right bit position to look at.

Or, given that you need to find the index into an array of 50 integers, use the 5 KB of space to store the indexes into the array of 50 integers, with perhaps -1 indicating that the number is not in use.

```
int main_array[50];
signed char aux_array[5000];

// initialize aux_array to all -1
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(aux_array); i++)
    aux_array[i] = -1;
// for each value `v` in main_array, store its index `i` in `aux_array[v]`
for (int i = 0; i < num_values; i++)
{
    int v = main_array[i];
    if (aux_array[v] != -1)
        ...non-unique data in main_array...
    aux_array[v] = i;
}
```

The inverse lookup checks in `aux_array` to see if the index is -1 (not present) or non-negative to indicate where it is found.  This is an inverted index.  If you end up needing more than 127 values, you can switch to `unsigned char` or `short` instead of `signed char` (with appropriate adjustments to the marker value, `-1` in my example).

Hashing is probably not cost effective.

Comment: actually I have a constant array of fixed size 50 and the value of this not going to change in the entire life cycle of the project. So I already have the set of values and I want to generate unique hash for those values only. If it is a generic case then the thing you are saying is absolutely correct. If you want the values, I can also provide that.